# Read an Amazon Cloudfront API Result in PHP

Tags: php, api, amazon-web-services

I've got a PHP script that submits Invalidation requests to Amazon's Cloudfront via API's.

I can capture the response, but it comes back as text basically looking like this:

```
HTTP/1.0 201 Created
Content-Type: text/xml
Location: https://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/2012-07-01/distribution/distribution ID/invalidation/invalidation ID

<Invalidation xmlns="http://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-07-01/">
   <Id>IDFDVBD632BHDS5</Id>
   <Status>InProgress</Status>
   <CreateTime>2013-04-16T19:37:58Z</CreateTime>   
   <InvalidationBatch>
      <Paths>
         <Items>
            <Path>/image1.jpg</Path>
         </Items>
      </Paths>
      <CallerReference>20130416090001</CallerReference>
   </InvalidationBatch>
</Invalidation>
```

I basically just want to grab the status value, and I suppose I could do it via Regex or some string manipulation, but I'm assuming there is a better way to convert the returned data into an object and access it properly.

I tried:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($data);
```

But $data doesn't work because it literally contains the header portion "HTTP/1.0 201..."

Anyone know the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What script are you using? Have you considered using the AWS SDK for PHP (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php)?

Using the AWS SDK for PHP you could do the following:

```
// Instantiate a CloudFront client
$cloudfront = \Aws\CloudFront\CloudFrontClient::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'your-aws-access-key-id',
    'secret' => 'your-aws-secret-key',
));

// Get the status of an invalidation
$invalidationStatus = $cloudfront->getInvalidation(array(
    'DistributionId' => 'your-distribution-id',
    'Id'             => 'your-invalidation-id',
))->get('Status');
```

Comment: I had been looking into it and actually just downloaded it today.  Will give this code a try and see how it goes. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Usually the Http client library should do that, you didn't mention the used one.

Still parsing that response should be simple as:

```
$dom->loadXML(substr($data, strpos("\n\n", $data)+2))
```

Answer (score -2):

Got this figured out by doing the following.

```
$resp = substr($resp, strpos($resp, "\r\n\r\n")+4); // This strips out the header

$outputxml = simplexml_load_string($resp); // Converts it to an object in PHP which can be fed back more easily
```